# Is it possible to enable an HSP/HFP profile in Raspian Bullseye?

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I am running Raspian Bullseye (Debian 11) on a RaspberryPi 4b and would like to use my Apple AirPods as a 2-way headset. I've done lots of digging, followed this tutorial by Youness (https://youness.net/raspberry-pi/bluetooth-headset-raspberry-pi-3-ad2p-hsp) and bought an Asus BT400 to use, just in case it mattered.

At the end of that I could see an hsp/hfp profile but it was labeled as `available = no`.

I tried to go the "ofono" route but was stopped when I tried to load phonesim with `Unable to locate package ofono-phonesim`. I saw a post about replacing Pulseaudio with Pipewire and went through that process until I came to another dead-end with `Failed to restart pipewire-pulse.service: Unit pipewire-pulse.service not found.`

So, I'm asking, has anyone successfully implemented a 2-way (hsp/hfp) headset audio profile, hardwired or bluetooth, in Bullseye? (and why is this so hard??).

Comment: Bluetooth support in RPi has sucked forever. There may be a way forward for you, but it will require considerable effort. Many (I think) have simply given up wrt anything BT on RPi.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Seamus. It seemed like that was the situation but I was hoping there might be a way out. So even with a wired headset it can't (reasonably) be done?

Comment: I honestly can't answer your question... I gave up on BT on RPi a few years ago, and decided I just wouldn't devote any more time to it unless or until the RPi manufacturer put some effort into sorting the problems. They have not done that. I'll guess there are some who use BT on RPi regularly, but I've not seen anyone here with any expertise for years. You might have better luck trying the RPi forums.